# How to map or transform one json type schema to another

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mapping

I am geeting data in json format from different customers row by row. For example:-

`input_data = {"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}`

There maybe a possibility that some customer send data like:

`input_data = {"username": "Ethen Hunt", "address": {"address_name": "Moscow", "address_id": 574}}`

So I have created my own schema that is:

`input_mapped = {"user": "" , "address": {"name": "", "id": }}`

so that even if I get input_data with changed key names, I still be able to get it and do further operations.

So instead of hard coding each "input_data" key value pair to the my created "input_mapped" dictionary. 
Is there a way I can do some json mapping or something else to do this.

It will be very kind of you to help

Comment: Does the input data always contains the same number of keys?

Comment: hey Shubham .. if the number of "input_data" keys equal to number of "input_mapped" keys, only then mapping needs to be done